# Java probability randomizer

Tags: java

I need to know if there is a way to assign a number a range to a string and have a randomizer select a number, and depending on what number it gives that string back. I know that is confusing so heres an example,

```
item1 = 0 to 15
item2 = 16 to 35
item3 = 36 to 65
item4 = 66 to 85
item5 = 86 to 95
item6 = 96 to 99
```

now say the randomizer generates the number 63 so in return you would get item3

Thanks

Comment: How many possible items do you need to do this for?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start with generating a nr from 0-100 then use if-else clauses to give back your string.

Comment: Each item should have a `double weight` which, altogether (for all items) sums to one.  Then you simply generate a random number between 0 and 1 and figure out which item the value is for (similar to how you did it, but instead of 0 --> 100 do 0.00 --> 1.00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple way, if the probabilities, number of items, and the items themselves don't change:

```
public String getRandomString() {
    int number = (int)(Math.random() * 100)
    if(number >= 0 && number <= 15) return "item1";
    if(number >= 16 && number <= 35) return "item2";
    if(number >= 36 && number <= 65) return "item3";
    if(number >= 66 && number <= 85) return "item4";
    if(number >= 86 && number <= 95) return "item5";
    if(number >= 96 && number <= 99) return "item6";

    // the computer will never get to here, but the compiler doesn't know that
    // (though it might happen if you change the numbers above, and don't
    // cover all the numbers 1 to 99)
    throw new RuntimeException("this shouldn't happen!");
}
```

Comment: There is no need to check lower bound if you are testing in ascending order.

Comment: @immibis now how you I put the outcome of the randomizer in a System.out.println

Comment: @baju true, but I thought it might make it more obvious how it works (for the asker).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `NavigableMap`. This lets you assign a weight to an item, and select items randomly based on their weight using the [ceilingEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#ceilingEntry(K)) method.

```
Random rand = new Random();
...
int rnd = rand.nextInt(totalWeight + 1);
String elem = map.ceilingEntry(rnd).getValue();
```

To generate your map, you simply do the following. Each item is added to the map with the total weight for it, plus all items before it. In your case you don't have to add up that running total as you already have your ranges.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
String[] items = new String[]{"item1","item2","item3","item4","item5","item6"};
int[] weights = new int[]{15,35,65,85,95,99};

int totalWeight = 0; // track this for use in random number generation
for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
    totalWeight = weights[i];
    map.put(totalWeight, items[i]);
}
```